# Extension function which is supposed to return an object returns null

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, view

**Utility** object

```
 fun Fragment.showMaterialClockPickerAndSetAlarm() : Alarm? {
   
    var alarm: Alarm? = null
    val materialTimePicker: MaterialTimePicker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
    .build()
    materialTimePicker.show(parentFragmentManager, getString(R.string.alarm))
    materialTimePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {

    val pickedHour: Int = materialTimePicker.hour
    val pickedMinute: Int = materialTimePicker.minute
    val formattedTime: String

      .........//some codes to assign those variables above

    alarm = Alarm(
            time = formattedTime,
            hour = pickedHour,
            minute = pickedMinute
        )
 
      }
   return alarm
 }
```

In my **fragment**

```
showMaterialClockPickerAndSetAlarm()?.let { it1 -> alarmViewModel.createAlarm(it1) }
```

But this always returns a null alarm object

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: You only assign your variables and `alarm` value when your onclicklistener is called but your function returns immediately so it has no chance to return anything other than `null`.

Comment: It's the same issue as the above linked question except you have a click listener instead of an API call, but adding a click listener is an asynchronous call just like an API call. So, you should be able to find an explanation there.

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04, got it working!

Also, thanks Pawel for that explanation.